# How to find the position of specific element in a list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list like this:

```
 website =    ['http://freshtutorial.com/install-xamp-ubuntu/', 'http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-xampp-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-12-04/', 'http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2149654', 'http://andyhat.co.uk/2012/07/installing-xampp-32bit-ubuntu-11-10-12-04/', 'http://askubuntu.com/questions/303068/error-with-tar-command-cannot-install-xampp-1-8-1-on-ubuntu-13-04', 'http://askubuntu.com/questions/73541/how-to-install-xampp']
```

I want to search if the following list contain the certain URL or not.

URL would be in this format : `url = 'http://freshtutorial.com'`

The website is the 1st element of a list. Thus, I want to print *1* **not 0**.

I want everything in the loop so that if there's no website with that URL, it would go again and dynamically generate the list and again search for the website.

I have done this upto now:

```
for i in website:
    if url in website:
        print "True"
```

I can't seem to print the position and wrap everything in loop. Also, is it better to use `regex` or `if this in that` syntax. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete program:

```
def search(li,ur):
    for u in li:
        if u.startswith(ur):
            return li.index(u)+1        
    return 0

def main():
    website = ['http://freshtutorial.com/install-xamp-ubuntu/', 'http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-xampp-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-12-04/', 'http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2149654', 'http://andyhat.co.uk/2012/07/installing-xampp-32bit-ubuntu-11-10-12-04/', 'http://askubuntu.com/questions/303068/error-with-tar-command-cannot-install-xampp-1-8-1-on-ubuntu-13-04', 'http://askubuntu.com/questions/73541/how-to-install-xampp']
    url = 'http://freshtutorial.com'
    print search(website,url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for i, v in enumerate(website, 1):
    if url in v:
        print i
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `if url in v`, to actually find http://freshtutorial.com in website[0]?

Comment: Enumerate takes an optional keyword argument "start", which allows one to begin indexing at 1: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Answer (score 1):

The code -

```
for i in range(0,len(website)):
    current_url = website[i]
    if url in current_url:
         print i+1
```

It's a simple for loop.